# 18.04 HP Pavilion desktop "No Wi-fi Adapter Found"

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

This Q has been asked times before on here, going by a search for the message, but all the answers have been immensely convoluted and impractical in my situation. I have installed Ubuntu on many other machines over many years and know my way around it. I'll give it a quick go anyway:

I've installed Linux 18.04 from USB on a HP Pavilion desktop literally straight out of the box. During the installation I wasn't prompted for wifi details, so clearly the installation didn't pick up the Wifi adaptor. Clicking on Settings / Wifi it says "No Wi-fi Adapter (sic) Found". The adaptor definitely works in Windoze 10 so clearly Ubuntu is lacking the driver.

Linux and hardware drivers is a problem going back to when I started using it in the Jurassic, but I'd thought it had been resolved in modern versions. Are there any quick fixes to this that don't involve abstruse and complex command lines, as suggested in other Qs on this topic? Also suggested is physical connection to the router which is not a physical option as one's upstairs and one's downstairs. I do have another machine, on which I'm writing this, on which I could download drivers.

Alternatively, is it worth me downloading 2 gigs of Ubuntu 19.10 and installing that?

The installation is not important - I just want a dual-boot desktop but can live with just Windoze, inferior and insecure as it is. I don't want to spend any significant time on a fix.

If there's no relatively simple fix, can anyone advise on how to remove the Ubuntu installation, and/or replace it with another distro?

Comment: So what do you really want? To fix the Wi-Fi issue or remove Ubuntu? We don't know what is your wireless device. To find this out it is required to run some terminal commands. If that is too difficult, then remove Ubuntu,

Comment: Every time a manufacturer chooses a new part based solely on Windows compatibility, we get to do this all over again, and 19.10 is no guarantee of instant resolution. We may repeat may be able to find the WiFi HW if you provide the HP parts model number from the serial number sticker; 'model' numbers anywhere else on the PC are marketing buzzwords and not helpful. Otherwise, open a terminal window and do `lspci -v -s` then copy the results, click edit here, and paste the results int your question so we can learn what HP put in your machine.

Comment: To check on available network drivers run `sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'` and copy/paste output in question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. (1) is very old skool tech patronising. As it happens, I have run many *nix systems as admin during my 25-year IT career (now retired) so do have a little experience with the terminal ;-)

What do I want? To run Ubuntu on a new PC without having to spend hours on installation. It's an optional extra. If it can't be installed, then no bother, I'll try another distro or stick with Windoze.

The other comments are useful and I'll get back on them later today